# How is a dictionary created and updated in java?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to create a Hash-table of "messengers" for a discord java bot. I am doing this project to help me learn java. I am initialising a Hash-table inside a public method that is connected to an event listener. I don't want to reset it each time an event occurs. This is my current code:

```
public class botListeners extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        super.onMessageReceived(event);

        // ISSUE HERE 
        Hashtable<String, Integer> messangerDict = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

        if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
            String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
            System.out.println("A message has been sent: " + message);
           
            String messenger = event.getAuthor().getAsTag();

            if (messangerDict.containsKey(event.getAuthor().getAsTag())){
                messangerDict.put(messenger, messangerDict.get(messenger) + 1);

            }else {
                messangerDict.put(event.getAuthor().getAsTag(), 1);
            }

            System.out.println(messangerDict.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

My current output, each time I write a message to the "guild" is this:

```
A message has been sent: as
{USERTAG=1}
A message has been sent: s
{USERTAG=1}
```

I would like it to increment each time, i.e the second should be 2, not 1.

Comment: you should create an AtomicLong object as a field of the EventListener, not as a local variable in the same method(onMessageReceived)

Comment: You probably should use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `Hashtable`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `HashTable` every time the method executes, so each time the method exits your `HashTable` goes away. Create it as a field of the class instead, like so:

```java
public class botListeners extends ListenerAdapter {

    Hashtable<String, Integer> messangerDict = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        super.onMessageReceived(event);

        if (!event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
// ...
```